# How to create a efficient co-occurrence in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I am trying to create a co-occurrence matrix in python but looking for some efficient ways to do it.

My dataset looks like this:

```
total_labels = ['a','b','c','d']

occ = [['a','b'],['c','d'],['a','c'],['d'],['a','c','d']]
```

And I am expecting the output like this:

```
data_mat = [[0, 1 , 2, 1],
            [1, 0,  0, 0],
            [2, 0,  0, 2],
            [1, 0,  2, 0]]
```

which is actually:

```
               a  b   c  d
data_mat = a [[0, 1 , 2, 1],
            b [1, 0,  0, 0],
            c [2, 0,  0, 2],
            d [1, 0,  2, 0]]
```

What I have tried is:

```
import numpy as np

m_matrix = np.zeros([4,4])

for m in range(len(total_labels)):
    for j in range(len(total_labels)):
        for k in occ:
            if set((total_labels[m],total_labels[j])).issubset(set(k)):
                m_matrix[m,j]+=1
```

which is giving :

```
array([[3., 1., 2., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [2., 0., 3., 2.],
       [1., 0., 2., 3.]])
```

But as you can see there is no connection between (a,a) and (b,b) etc ( self loops ) but it's giving values there.

How can create data_mat without using many loops?

Comment: Can there really be occurrences of a value with itself?

Comment: @ALollz self-occurrences doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Just wanted to check because if a group were `['a', 'a']`, my solution wouldn't count that, though you could imagine perhaps that should for some application since it's different from `['a']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

self-`merge` followed by `crosstab`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(occ).stack().rename('val').reset_index().drop(columns='level_1')

df = df.merge(df, on='level_0').query('val_x != val_y')
pd.crosstab(df.val_x, df.val_y)
```

#### Output:

```
val_y  a  b  c  d
val_x            
a      0  1  2  1
b      1  0  0  0
c      2  0  0  2
d      1  0  2  0
```

---

If need only those labels you supplied can do:

```
(pd.crosstab(df.val_x, df.val_y)
     .reindex(total_labels, axis=0).reindex(total_labels, axis=1))
```

Or filter before the merge (probably smarter):

```
df = df.loc[df.val.isin(total_labels)]
```

Comment: Hi, There are two issues, first is it's not including all the columns , my actual labels are 90 but it's returning 80x80 matrix
second can we sort it before merging?

Comment: The reindex should ensure all 90 values are represented in the final table, which you will need to then `.fillna(0)`. If they aren't being included it's because they have no co-occurrences. What does the sorting accomplish? Again `.reindex` will give you a DataFrame with columns in the order of `total_labels`

Comment: I tried to add .fillna but not working, can you modify the answer where and how I can do it?

Comment: Ok I did but now it's 91

Comment: Is there perhaps a repeated or unwanted value in total_labels?

Comment: I am doing like this :

`pd.DataFrame(final_labels).fillna(0).stack().rename('val').reset_index().drop(columns='level_1')`